# I need to change specific characters in file names to uppercase

Tags: python

I have roughly 20,000 files in a single directory whose filenames I need to change in the following manner:

Target_file_name.jpg

to

Target_File_Name.jpg

All of the filenames have at least two words in them, but some have three or even four, and all have the individual words separated by underscore characters.  There are no spaces in any of the filenames.  How would I do this?

I know I can do something like:

```
import os
 
for x in os.listdir():
    splitName = x.split("_")
    for y in splitName:
```

but I am not sure how to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that very easy by titling the string:

```
import os
 
for x in os.listdir():
    os.rename(x, x.title())
```

However if you do not like the fact it will also capitalize the `jpg` part, you can do the following:

```
import os
 
for x in os.listdir():
    os.rename(x, x.title().replace("Jpg", "jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a filename like `Target_file_name.jpg`, you can capitalize all the `_` delimited words like this:

```
>>> orig_name = 'Target_file_name.jpg'
>>> fixed_name = '_'.join(word.capitalize() for word in orig_name.split('_'))
>>> print(fixed_name)
Target_File_Name.jpg
```

To perform that change on all the files in a directory:

```
import os

def capitalize_words(fn):
    return '_'.join(word.capitalize() for word in fn.split('_'))

for fn in os.listdir():
    os.rename(fn, capitalize_words(fn))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate through the split I think. You can just use the [title()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_title.asp) method to capitalize the filename and use `os.rename` to change the filename

```
for x in os.listdir():
    os.rename(x, x.title())
```